# resuming the session with last visited page

Tags: grails, groovy

I want the user to be taken to the last visited page upon clicking the resume button. I am passing the id to the controller.

```
<input type="button" value="Resume" onclick="window.location.href='/wizard/submission/resume/${submission.id}'" />
```

The controller logic is as below

```
def resume = {
        def id = params.id

        def test = (getDomainObjectType() as Class).get(id)

        session[getSessionObjectName()] = test;

        LOG.debug("resuming ${test}")
        redirect(action: "wizard");
    }
```

and the wizard logic is as below:(its so long as of now)

```
nextView = (int) postProcessedValues.next;
 if (nextView == null) {
                redirect(action: "index");
                //nextView = 0; //question is what to do here. Maybe redirect back to the index page instead...
            }
```

Help me in implementing the logic here.

Comment: please let me know if you need other code of mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the solution by using pagetracker of type int and by preserving the value of it in database and to display the associated page upon clicking the resume button.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you might want to investigate using Grails Web Flow support -> http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/web%20flow.html

This allows continuations and easier ways of knowing 'where' the user is in a complex wizard or 'stateful' web app (e.g. Shopping Cart) so you can 'resume' an operation they might have navigated away from it.  This also allows your app to 'child wizards' so to speak or in Web Flow terminology 'subflows'.  These are useful if you want your user to do some extended operations with state that won't effect the state of the main wizard if they choose to cancel out.

Is does push more state to a users session and you have to make sure you give things minimal scope so they go away as quickly as possible.  But invaluable if your user interactions complex and depend on where they are in an extended action.

Comment: hi Todd, thanks for the response...I have implemented this in a different way....using page tracker associated with each page and on clicking resume takes me to the page by identifying the pagetracker. thanks for your answer once again